# Using split() and checking for a 2nd element

Tags: java, split, binary-search-tree, user-input, indexoutofboundsexception

I have code for a Binary Search Tree that will accept user input such as
`insert 3` and it will call the insert function on 3. When I try to call a function that requires no arguments like my traverse function it will give an out of bounds error unless the user input is `traverse 0` I want to call it by using just `traverse`, here is my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int quit = 0;
    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Accept user input and call funtions
    while(quit != 1)
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the instructions to perform (type quit when done):");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        String[] instruction = input.split(" ");
        String function = instruction[0].toLowerCase();
        String parameter = instruction[1];
        //What to do with user input
        if(function.equals("insert"))// for insert
        {
            int key = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
            bst.insert(key);
            System.out.println(parameter + " was inserted successfully!");
        }
        else if(function.equals("delete"))// for delete
        {
            int key = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
            if(bst.delete(key) == true)
                System.out.println(parameter + " was deleted successfully!");
            else
                System.out.println(parameter + " does not exist.");
            bst.delete(key);
        }
        else if(function.equals("search"))// for search
        {
            int key = Integer.parseInt(parameter);
            if(bst.search(key) == true)
                System.out.println(parameter + " was found!");
            else
                System.out.println(parameter + " not found.");
            bst.search(key);
        }
        else if(function.equals("traverse"))// for traverse
        {
            bst.traverse(BinarySearchTree.root);
        }
    }

}//end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem occurs when you try to assign `instruction[1]` to `parameter`. If there is no space character in your input string then the `split` method will return an array of length 1 and you will get an out of range exception when you try to access the second element.

The solution is:

```
if (input.equals("traverse")) {
    ...
} else {
    String[] instructions = input.split(" ");
    assert instruction.length == 2;
    String function = instruction[0].toLowerCase();
    int key = Integer.parseInt(instruction[1]);
    ...
}
```

There are better ways to model commands. Ideally you'd use a [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) rather than `if` statements. But if you don't want to go to that trouble you should at least consider using patterns to make the parsing more robust.

```
Pattern commandPattern = Pattern.compile("(traverse|search|delete|insert) *(\\d*)");
Matcher matcher = commandPattern.match(in.nextLine());
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Illegal command. Try again.");
    matcher = commandPattern.match(in.nextLine());
}
switch (matcher.group(1).toLowerCase()) {
    case "traverse":
        bst.traverse(root);
        break;
    case "delete":
        int deleteKey = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
        if (bst.delete(deleteKey)) {
            ...
```

Comment: I feel like there is a more elegant solution but this works, thank you!

Comment: Yes there are far more elegant solutions than this. I'll add a suggestion to my answer.